# PDE realated to heat equation with exponential additive term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve a PDE realated to heat equation with exponential additive term

$${\partial u\over\partial t}={1\over x^2}{\partial\over\partial x}(x^2{\partial u\over\partial x})+e^u$$

I dervived this equation from thermal explosion's equation so it is similar to heat equation with reaction term $e^u$

Does this equation has analytic solution? If so, what is it?

Comment: Without thinking about it too much, my instinct is "probably not"